# Modifying DateTimeField django

Tags: django, timestamp

im using djang's "DateTimeField" and it saves the data like "YYYY/MM/DD HH/MM/SS", right? but i just want to save the date like "YYYY/MM/DD" there's a way to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using **DateField** ?